# Is there a "try" equivalent or work around in Hive?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hive

I'm trying to pull an error code from a string, in Athena I can use:

`split_part(text_column,'Error No.:',2)`  -- in order to get what is on the right of the error message

and

```
split_part(split_part(text_column,'Error No.:',2),',',1)
```

-- to get what is to the right of the "Error No." phrase and to the left of the comma

so: `concat("Error No.:",split_part(split_part(text_column,'Error No.:',2),',',1))` gets me what I want in athena.  Split part is not available in Hive.

So I tried:

```
concat('Error No.',split(split(text_column,'OTTOERR')[2],',')[1])
```

and I get the error

> Array subscript out of bounds

But:

```
concat('Error No.',try(split(split(text_column,'OTTOERR')[2],',')[1]))
```

works.  But you cannot use the "try" command in Hive.  Does anyone know a workaround for this?  Or how to just break down what try is doing so I could find one?

Comment: Which of your two splits isn't working?  Show some sample data where it isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, should have given more context.  It's the second split (indexing the [2] in athena, would be a [1] in hive but same idea), since there are situations where the error code is not there so there is no second piece of the array.
So the upper bound is the issue not the lower bound.

Comment: You can use `locate` with a case statement to test if the string is present, split if it is, etc.

Comment: Please provide the initial string examples and what should be extracted. Most probably you do not need two split in this case. split in hive uses regexp. you can probably use single regexp_extract, and if it cannot extract, it returns empty string, you can wrap in the case expression...